# Chrome HTML & CSS (Bootstrap 5.0) not translating to Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I have an HTML page with a bunch of divs of varying sizes (depending on viewport and %s), and it is not rendering cleanly to Safari on larger devices, although it is on Chrome and on Safari on smaller mobile devices.

I have attached screenshots of the various views below. Relevant HTML, JS and CSS (using Bootstrap 5.0 throughout) are as follows:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        ...
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex g-0 gap-3" id="map-div">
            <div class="row-fluid d-flex g-0 justify-content-around" id="map-row">
                <div class="d-flex g-0 fade-in" id="map-col">
                    <svg id="map-svg">
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
const svg = d3.select("#map-svg")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 960 600")
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 99%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
/*map containers*/
#map-div {
    padding: 1.5%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #map-div {
        height: 48vw;
        max-height: 75%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1065px) and (max-width: 1162px) {
    #map-div {
        height: 45vw;
        max-height: 72%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #map-div {
        height: 50vw;
        max-height: 68%;
        min-height: 64%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #map-div {
        height: 56vw;
        max-height: 69%;
        min-height: 56%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
    #map-div {
        height: 56vw;
        max-height: 48%;
        min-height: 40%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #map-div {
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
#map-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#map-col {
    height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
    #map-col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    #map-col {
        padding-right: 2.5%;
    }
}
```

**Correct on Chrome:**

[image]

**Correct on Safari (*mobile*):**

[image]

****Incorrect** on Safari (***desktop***):**

[image]

**Incorrect on Chrome with width:100% (*desktop*)**

[image]

**Incorrect on Safari with width:100% (*desktop*)**

[image]

Comment: The SVG element in your code doesn't have any styles applied, neither it has the viewBox or width/height attributes.

Comment: @tromgy sorry updated to include JS that adds attributes to SVG!

Comment: Adding `width: 100%` to the default `#row-col` selector seems to fix the issue: https://codepen.io/tromgy/pen/XWePBgx

Comment: @tromgy added the 2 new incorrect views with `width: 100%`. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to quite solve the issue (also introduces the Chrome col stretching which throws off the zoom buttons to the left, and stretches the legend to the right, as in the added screenshot).

Comment: (*Specifically related to the `justify-content-around` class on `#map-row`)